# Raven Puzzle - How to solve it?

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

I was doing the Raven Progressive Matrix test when I got stuck and couldn't solve 2 questions.

SEE :

[image]

Ps. The answer is marked in Green.  Anyone could help me with any insights?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, where did this question come from? Please include the source. I do remember seeing this somewhere so you did not create it. If you did, please add a note to say that you created it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember the source,

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:

> The first one on the second row. Each step, the dots move by one square to the right, wrapping back to the first square on the next row when they're at the end of the row. They alternate between full and not full whenever they pass through a white square.

Question 2:

> The third one on the first row. You can see it as an addition: dots inside the circle represent positive numbers, dots outside represent negative numbers (or vice-versa). The third item on each row is the sum of the first two. This rule also works vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Question 2:

> Dots on the outside counter dots on the inside when added horizontally and vertically. Also only one kind of dot per circle (otherwise there are multiple answers - row 1, columns 1,2,3).